# hasCls() not working for my Extjs Grid

Tags: extjs4.2

i am applying css for a clicked record in my grid like below

```
 listeners: {
    select: function(record,rowIndex) {
        this.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex, 'green');
    }}
```

i need to check on a condition whether css is present or not, i am trying to check like this

```
 select: function(record,rowIndex) {
        this.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex, 'green');
        if(this.getView().hasCls('green')){}
    }
```

which is always returning false. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bellow way to check if the specified CSS class exists.

```js
var row = this.getView().getNode(rowIndex, false);
if (row) {
  console.log( Ext.fly(row).hasCls('green') );
}
```